# Custom action for add_argument() - both bool and string types

Tags: python, argparse

```
parser.add_argument('-w', '--wireshark', dest='wireshark')
```

I would like to that parameter `-w` define in `add_argument` behave like:

- if present at CLI - True
- if not present at CLI - False
- if preset at CLI user can add string like  -w "{'flag': True}"
- default whould be nice `bool` or `string`

So, as you can see I need both action `store_true` and `store` at the same time. I try extend `argparse.Action` write custom one but I failed.

Comment: `nargs='?'` with appropriate `default` and `const` gives a 3 way action.  You may also need a custom `type` function.

Comment: @hpaulj worked!     `action_start.add_argument('-al', '--alarms', dest='alarms', nargs='?', const=True, default=False, type=str_as_dict)` and **str_as_dict()** do just `py_dict = literal_eval(param_value)`